# Converting IQueryable string to compare against string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to build up a multiselect of admin users to toggle between assigned or unassigned. All seems to be correct except it doesn't like where I'm attempting to assign true or false to the `IsInRole` property of the `UsersInRoleViewModel`.

The error is:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Any assistance is appreciated!

```
public ActionResult EditRoles()
{
    // AdminUsers
    var adminId = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator").Select(r => r.Id);

    var users = db.Users.Select(u => new UsersInRoleViewModel 
                                     {
                                         UserId = u.Id,
                                         DisplayName = u.DisplayName, 
                                         IsInRole = u.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId == adminId)
                                     });

    var adminUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsInRole).Select(n => n.UserId).ToArray();

    var adminMultiSelect = new MultiSelectList(users, "Id", "DisplayName", adminUsers);

    var model = new UserSelectListsViewModel { AdminUsers = adminMultiSelect, SelectedAdmins = adminUsers, DevUsers = null, PMUsers = null, SubUsers = null };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You're assigning an enumerable where it wants a bool (presumably). Which role is `IsInRole` supposed to pertain to?

Comment: the id in the role table associated with 'Administrator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin Id is a list of ids.  You need to change it to

> var adminId = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator").Select(r => r.Id).First().ToString();

```
 public ActionResult EditRoles()
        {
            //AdminUsers

            var adminId = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator").Select(r => r.Id).First().ToString();

            var users = db.Users.Select(u => new UsersInRoleViewModel 
                                                    {
                                                        UserId = u.Id,
                                                        DisplayName = u.DisplayName, 
                                                        IsInRole = u.Roles.Where(r => adminId == r.RoleId))
                                                    });

            var adminUsers = users.Where(u => u.IsInRole).Select(n => n.UserId).ToArray();

            var adminMultiSelect = new MultiSelectList(users, "Id", "DisplayName", adminUsers);

            var model = new UserSelectListsViewModel { AdminUsers = adminMultiSelect, SelectedAdmins = adminUsers, DevUsers = null, PMUsers = null, SubUsers = null };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are doing two trips to db, one trip to get Admin RoleId, and second to get users with AdminRole = Yes/Now

Here is the same query in just one trip to db instead of two in your case.

```
var adminUsers = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator")
                         .SelectMany(r => r.Users.Select(u => new UsersInRoleViewModel 
                                             {
                                                 UserId = u.Id,
                                                 DisplayName = u.DisplayName)).toList();

var users = db.Users.Select(u=> new UsersInRoleViewModel 
                                {
                                   UserId = u.Id,
                                   DisplayName = u.DisplayName)).toList();

var adminMultiSelect = new MultiSelectList(users, "Id", "DisplayName", adminUsers);

var model = new UserSelectListsViewModel { AdminUsers = adminMultiSelect, SelectedAdmins = adminUsers, DevUsers = null, PMUsers = null, SubUsers = null };
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work exactly as is, but it is a good idea.

Comment: Thats only getting me to the join table but I like the concept!

Comment: I thought you can always get all users just by doing db.Users.Select(mappingToViewModel).ToList(), any way updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `string.CompareOrdinal`

```cs
    string.CompareOrdinal("A","B")
    -1
    string.CompareOrdinal("B","A")
    1
    string.CompareOrdinal("A","A")
    0
```